# What is unsolved in CP Violation?

Tags: particle-physics, cp-violation

I learnt about [CP Violation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP_violation) in my Quantum Information Theory and Particle Physics courses. However I have not understood what exactly has not been solved yet about CP Violation. I thought that the standard model is able to predict CP Violation perfectly well.

Comment: Why is it so big? The Standard Model predicts some, to be sure, but not nearly enough to explain the amount of matter vs. antimatter we see. Also, why doesn't the strong force have any CP violation?

Comment: The absence of antimatter in the universe has nothing to do with the CP violation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard model does indeed describe/predict CP violation in the quark sector perfectly well (dammit!)    But it does not explain why the universe we're in is full of matter and empty of antimatter.